# Can't locate this input element selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to locate the input `“to”` field on this webpage: [Link here](https://www.reddit.com/message/compose/)
(sorry about having to login to see it)

My code:

```
name_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='compose-message']/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/textarea")
```

But that gives the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@id='compose-message']/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/textarea"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

For some reason this page is the only page that has given me any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the `textarea` **web elements** are wrapped inside `iframes`.

Using `explicit waits`, does give your script a stability that it need.

Also prefer to use `css selector` over `xpath`.

In `Selenium`, to access `elements` which are inside of iframe, we need to switch the focus of `webdriver` to `iframe`. Like below

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='/message/compose/']")))
```

and once you are inside this `iframe` you can interact with `to` input web element. Like below

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "to"))).send_keys('something here')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='message']/following-sibling::div/descendant::textarea"))).send_keys('Some message')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Also, remember to switch to `default content` when you are done with `iframe.`

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

In order to work with **elements** which are outside of this `iframe`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your code worked for locating the to field. I tried getting to the message field, but can't seem to follow the same pattern with `message_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='text']")))`. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: The xpath that you are using has 2 matching nodes, so try this instead `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='message']/following-sibling::div/descendant::textarea"))).send_keys('Some message')` I have updated above as well.

Comment: "Most of the `textarea` web elements are wrapped inside `iframes`." => I don't think that's True as a "generic" Statement..., you may want to add an "... on this Site"... // "Also prefer to use `css selector` over `xpath`." => Yep, same Opinion... (Like I tried to explain to @OP in one of their several parallel Threads on several different Forums: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31754&p=88120#p88117 )

Answer (score 1):

The Element you are trying to find is in an `iframe`. Was able to find and send text to the elements with below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
import time

opt = ChromeOptions()
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe",options=opt)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/message/compose/")
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='saPujbGMyXRwqISHcmJH9']"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='to']").send_keys("Sample Text")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='usertext']//textarea").send_keys("Sample Text")

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all that element is inside an iframe. To access it you need to switch to that iframe. Also, your locator are not looking good.
Please try the following code:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'message')]")))
name_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='to']")))
```

To use the above expected conditions you will need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

use command CSS selector instead of XPath such as use below code.

```
yourwebsriver.find_elements_by_css_selector("textarea[name=text]").send_keys('something here')
```